# Custom render returning binary data to ajax call in django-rest framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am making an ajax call to the rest api and I expect to get the raw binary data.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'verify',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "url": url,
            }),
            dataType: "application/octet-stream",
            success: function(response, textStatus, jqXhr) {
                if (response) {
                    try {
                        // do something
                    } catch (e) {
                        displayError(e);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // loader.remove();
                // $.unblockUI();
                console.log(textStatus); // parsererror
                console.log(errorThrown); // No conversion from text to application/octet-stream
                var err = parseError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                displayError(err);
            }
        });
```

The restful API is

```
from rest_framework.renderers import BaseRenderer
class BinaryRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    charset = None
    format = '.bin'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data


from rest_framework.response import Response
import urllib2
class MyView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (BinaryRenderer,)
    def post(self, request):
        url = request.DATA['url']
        conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        byte = conn.read()
        conn.close()
        return Response({'blob':byte})
```

The server returns code 200, but the ajax jumps to error due to `parseError` and `errorThrown` shows `No conversion from text to application/octet-stream`.

Why the content-type of the response is `text`, but not `octet-stream`?

Thank you

Comment: there is no stream datatype for ajax. What are you trying to do with this response?

Comment: Actually, this is a zip binary data, so I want to decompress the zip binary data in the ajax callback.

Comment: that's not what ajax is meant for

Comment: Is there any other ways which can deal with the binary data?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue - getting binary data via AJAX.

[JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent](https://github.com/stuk/jszip-utils) saved the day.

```
JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent("path/to/file.zip", function (err, data) {
if(err) {
  throw err; // or handle the error
}
// do something with data
});
```

[Usage](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html#in-the-browser)
[Docs](http://stuk.github.io/jszip-utils/documentation/api/getbinarycontent.html)